# Is it possible to move a subversion repository to another provider and retain commit history

Tags: svn, version-control

We have a couple of projects that run on svn. I know I can simply export the code and commit it to the new repository location but this results in loss of commit history. Also I think git allows you to do this quite easily. You can just add a new remote location and push it. I maybe wrong, but this results in creating an exact copy of the repository(or specifically your working copy). Is this possible wiht svn. I don't mean svn relocate. I mean actually move to a repository with a different uuid. Let's say I want to move it over from my own server to google code, or beanstalkapp. Can this be done?

Comment: you should keep your uuid - you can set the new repo's uuid to the old one with svnadmin http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html

Comment: I am not sure if hosted svn services allow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If**

1. your old SCM-hosting has ability to create (and download to you) SVN-dumps
2. new SVN-hosting allow to load dumps into repository

you can move repository with full history, otherwise you'll FAIL

Comment: With [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html) (SVN 1.7+ distributions) you don't need full support from the remote hosts - you can dump & load from a client.

Comment: @alroc - yes, forgot to mention it